# How can I write this code less and better in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

How can I write this code less and better in Laravel?
I am writing this code to remove the / r character in the input text and also to calculate the number of characters in the text.

```
$removeRchar = Str::remove("\r", $request['message']);
    $length = Str::length($removeRchar);
    if ($length <= 70) {
        $pages = 1;
    } else {
        $pages = ceil($length / 70);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a [Stringable](https://laravel.com/api/9.x/Illuminate/Support/Stringable.html)

```php
$length = Str::of($request['message'])
    ->remove('\r')
    ->length();

$pages = ceil($length / 70);
```

If you don't want an extra page when you have a lenght of 70, 140 etc. you should add a check. For example:

```php
$pages = $lenght % 70 === 0 
    ? $lenght / 70
    : ceil($length / 70);
```